# How is delayed column generation any faster than ordinary simplex method?

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-optimization, linear-programming

I am interested in the algorithm for delayed column generation.  I understand the general idea of delayed column generation:  We are only adding columns to our solution if the column results in a negative reduced cost (in a minimization problem, obviously the opposite for maximization problem).

So, the reduced cost is given by $\bar{c_j}=c_j-{c_B}'B^{-1}A_j$, where:

- $B$ is the basis matrix
- ${c_B}'$ are the weights on the columns in the basis matrix
- $A_j$ is column $j$ in the matrix A from the linear program in standard form.

The above can be found in the Bertsimas text on page 232 in chapter 6.

We are looking for a reduced cost that is less than $0$ of course.  So, we have to examine every column $j$ in the matrix $A$ before determining that there is a column that can be added to our basis matrix.

If we need to examine all columns anyway, then I'm having trouble figuring out why/how this is any faster than solving the problem before including ALL the columns in the optimization problem in the beginning.

What obvious am I missing?

The sources for this are the canonical text Bertsimas available [here](https://www.u-cursos.cl/ingenieria/2010/1/IN3701/2/material_docente/bajar?id_material=289781).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In practice, the column generation problem is typically solved without explicitly enumerating all of the possible columns and checking the reduced cost of each column.  Instead, an optimization subproblem is solved to obtain a column with negative reduced cost, or if the subproblem is infeasible, show that there are no columns with negative reduced costs.

A good example of this can be found in Chapter 13 of Chvatal's Linear Programming textbook, where a column generation approach to the cutting-stock problem is developed.

Comment: So you're saying that it will include the very first column with a negative reduced cost into the basis? (the first column it finds).  Even though it will not be the column with the lowest reduced cost?

Comment: I am not of the age to vote, but +1

Comment: A lot depends on how the subproblem is solved.   In the cutting-stock problem example in Chvatal's book, a knapsack problem is solved to optimality to find the remaining column with the most negative reduced cost.

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't really answer my question.  Is it true that the delayed column generation method will just grab the first column it finds that has a reduced cost?

Comment: No, not in general.

Comment: Then I guess this comes back to my original question....I don't understand how delayed column generation is choosing which columns to include...and how it's any faster for handling large problems.

Comment: The key phrase in my answer is "without explicitly enumerating all of the possible columns"

Comment: If it is not enumerating all possible columns, @BrianBorchers and it is not grabbing the first column it finds that has a reduced cost, then how is it choosing which columns to include?  (I suppose that is a better way to phrase my question - sorry it took me so long).

Comment: I suggest that you read the chapter of Chvatal's book that I mentioned in my answer since it gives a very good example of how to find a column to enter the basis without checking all columns explicitly.  In that example, a small knapsack problem is solved to obtain a column with the optimal reduced cost.